# Login-check: Page_Load vs Page_PreRender? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a website where you must be logged in to access it, however, if the user lost the Session "loginID", the user should be kicked out immediately by a `if(Session["LoginID"] == null)` via MasterPage. But since im new to HTML/asp.net, Im not sure where I should actually have it, in Page_Load or Page_PreRender.

Does it even matter which one I have it in?

Using asp.net/c#

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Page_PreInIt` event for your problem to check if session is live or ended

```
protected void Page_PreInIt(object sender,EventsArgs e)
{
if(Session["LoginID"] == null)
{
// redirect to login if session is null
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}       
}
```

**Page Load:**

> The Page object calls the OnLoad method on the Page object, and then
>   recursively does the same for each child control until the page and
>   all controls are loaded. The Load event of individual controls occurs
>   after the Load event of the page

**Page PreRender**

> Raised after the Page object has created all controls that are
>   required in order to render the page, including child controls of
>   composite controls.  The Page object raises the PreRender event on the
>   Page object, and then recursively does the same for each child
>   control. The PreRender event of individual controls occurs after the
>   PreRender event of the page

[Read More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)